# Как оценить стоимость и срок реализации проекта?

Tags: android, ios, веб-программирование

Всем добрый день!

Помогите, пожалуйста, оценить стоимость проекта и возможные сроки реализации.

Есть идея игрового приложения для обучения школьников младших классов математике. Само по себе приложение не слишком сложное – уровень простой аркадной игры с несколькими режимами и статистикой. Приложение предполагается использовать на уроках для обучения. В качестве эксперимента планируется сначала внедрить его в одной школе, если идея окажется удачной, можно будет предлагать его другим школам.

Что требуется сделать: сайт, адаптированный для мобильных устройств.
Игровое приложение – браузерную версию (установленную на сайте), версию для мобильных устройств на базе Android и iOS.

Сайт предполагается использовать для организованного обучения и просмотра статистики. Имеется два типа пользователей – учителя и ученики. Ученики обучаются, используя приложение, учителя контролируют процесс обучения. Ученики также могут быть разбиты на группы (например, по классам). Приложение собирает статистику. Эта статистика должна быть видна учителю (для отслеживания прогресса учеников).

Дополнение: общались с потенциальными разработчиками, они оценили стоимость от 1.5 миллиона рублей со сроком в полгода. Насколько это адекватно?

Comment: срок вполне адекватный. По цене, вероятно, можно найти дешевле, но  окончательная стоимость будет зависеть от конкретных деталей (скажем, у вас почти ничего не сказано о сайте - его функциональности, дизайне и прочих подробностях). 
В любом случае объем работ достаточно большой, и меньше чем за полмиллиона адекватный исполнитель за работу не возьмется

Comment: Так приложение представлять собой игру должно или в виде тестов?

Comment: не думаю что можно найти дешевле если человек хочет три платформы, если только версию на мобильниках сделать той же браузерной через phonegap, да и то если заказчик хочет фикспрайс то нужно очень сильно закладываться на риски - ТЗ никакое

Comment: Тут 2 приложения под разные платформы + веб платформа + база данных + обработка данных и статистика. Для Москвы цена адекватная, в периферии наверное подешевле сделают. По срокам за пол года можно сделать стабильный проект, но наверняка надо будет ещё много допиливать :)

Comment: пишите максимально полное и точное ТЗ, и не выдумывайте задачи по ходу разработки. только тогда сможете сэкономить и на времени и на затратах. поможет также разделение задач по этапам - сайт (тоже можно разные части на этапы разбить), приложение для ios, приложение для android... 1,5кк это еще по божески за такую "идею".  
ЗЫ тестировать на всеразличных устройствах скорее всего придется вам, поэтому готовьте парк айфонов и гуглофонов.

Comment: так как проект детский, то чтоб выстрелил в дизайн вложится придется не слабо, это тоже увеличивает цену.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задача распадается на 4 компоненты:

1. Серверная часть
2. Браузерная часть (для desktop'а)
3. Часть для Android'а
4. Часть под iOS

Это более-менее независимые друг от друга компоненты - то есть они могут выполняться малосвязанными командами разработчиков, при условии что сначала пишется серверная часть, а потом можно параллелить 2, 3 и 4 части.

Теоретически 2, 3 и 4 часть можно написать под унифицированного тонкого клиента, который будет работать везде, но это теория - на практике так редко получается.

Касательно серверной части - сейчас это модно писать в архитектуре [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), существует множество готовых решений, бери да реализуй. Это не должно быть дорого.

Ну а далее для части 2 нанимайте похапистов (они дешёвые и их много). Для 3 и 4 желающих написать RESTful клиента тоже будет много - паттерн известный, уже многократно пройденный вдоль и поперек. Не думаю, что будет очень дорого.

Придется хорошо вложиться в дизайнеров это да - оценивать стоимость не берусь.

Ну а если вы отдадите 100% всего прожекта в одни руки - в итоге вы получите уникальное решение/закрытый черный ящик, на котором разработчик еще долго будет греть ручки (на поддержке), а оно вам надо?

**Update**

Собственно по стоимости и срокам. Серверную компоненту при наличии вменяемого ТЗ можно поднять за пару-тройку недель (зависит от количества сервисов), за вполне разумные деньги что-то в районе $2-3 тыс. - ну $5 это будет очень круто.

Все остальные компоненты каждая также обойдется по $2-3 штуки (максимум).

С дизайном сложнее - даже не скажу.

Я бы сделал итеративную разработку примерно такого плана:

- Итерация 1: реализуем примитивную серверную часть, сверху накидываем десктоп клиента на связке PHP+JS
- Итерация 2: заказываем дизайн на десктоп
- Итерация 3: доделываем серверную часть и добиваем десктопа
- Итерация 4: добиваем полный дизайн
- Итерация 5: пишем Android и iOS клиентов
- Итерация 6: адаптируем дизайн под Android и iOS

При таком подходе придется еще вложиться в финансирование управления проектом: $5-6 штук полюбасу - то есть должен быть некто, кто всю эту свору прогеров/дизигнеров будет держать на коротком поводке и не давать им расползаться.